# Redshift doesn't work without internet connection because of lacking location info

Tags: redshift

My redshift does only work if there is an internet connection on my notebook. Is there a workaround? It's not convenient that one can't specifiy this inside the software. This is my terminal output:

```
empedokles@thinkpad:~$ redshift
Trying location provider `geoclue'...
Started Geoclue provider `Geoclue Master'.
Service »geoclue« is used.
Could not get location (3 retries left): Geoclue master client has no usable Position providers.
Couldn't get position from Service.
empedokles@thinkpad:~$
```

Comment: You should add the specific error message to your post. It works for me without internets, so there probably is a workaround, but ppl can't help you without more info.

Comment: There is no error message, it just won't startup. But I can see it's trying to connect to the time zone in terminal if I type 'redshift'.

Comment: So it prints something and then dies or prints something and then hangs or what? In any case, you should include the output. If it's small, just add it to your question. If it's long, pastebin it and link it from your question.

Comment: @user3113723 The question has been reopened. Please post your answer!

Comment: @empedokles consider editing the title of the question to make it more obvious (to people searching) that the problem is a lack of location info.

Comment: Actually this error happens to me even with a working internet connection...

Comment: @landroni: Here too. This program is so much beta that it should be called zeta.

Comment: @empedokles No, it is not. It is rough around the edges, which indeed is worth fixing, but works nicely and gets the job done.

Comment: @landroni : Well If I push the icon nothing happens. Hence it's broken. I only can switch temparature over the commandline.

Answer (score 5):

Look at `/usr/share/doc/redshift/example-redshift.conf`. Note particularly the bit where `lat` and `lon` are assigned manually. Copy this file (or part of it, if you don't like all the settings) to `~/.config/redshift.conf`, figure out your latitude and longitude (with google maps?), and edit the manual override appropriately.

Note that you could probably have figured this out by looking at `man redshift`, `info redshift`, (which describe setting location manually) and the output of `dpkg -L redshift` (where you would have seen that it provided `example-redshift.conf`).

Comment: I'm not a techie. It's quite inconvenient that this software lacks a setting for it then.

Comment: I don't understand. It has a setting. You can pass lat/lon as a flag, or put it in a config file.

Comment: The menuicon of redshift has no setting. As a user I don't like to rely on commandline flags.

Comment: I don't know anything about menuicon settings. I don't use unity. In any case, in my opinion, you should mark my answer correct (try it first, even if you don't want to use it permanently), and then file a bug on launchpad about bad usability. In any case, you're likely to annoy people if you ask for a workaround for an issue your having, and then complain that it isn't the workaround you want. If you were looking specifically for a workaround using menuicon settings, you should have said so.

Comment: Also, as I say, I don't know exactly what a menuicon setting is (that doesn't appear to be standard terminology), but if it means the right-click menu for a launcher entry, I'm not sure that could be made to do anything useful other than specify that it shouldn't try to use geoclue. That wouldn't help if you hadn't specified the location some other way (probably in the config file).

Comment: Hi. Redshift has an icon in Unity. I don't find the example-redshift.conf under the path provided.

Comment: I gave you the wrong path before. Fixed above.